# Changing instance of a class from another class

Tags: class, object, methods

I am trying to use 1 class to change the values of another class.
My first class is Employees. My second class is address.

```
public class Employee {

private String name; 
private Address address;
```

constructors:

```
public Employee(){
    address = new Address(); 
    name = ""; 
}


public Employee(String name){
    this.name = name;
    this.address = new Address(); 
}


public String getAddress(){
    return address.getAddress();
}



public void changeAddress(String number, String street, String city, String province, String postalCode){


    address.setNumber(number);
    address.setStreet(street);
    address.setCity(city);
    address.setProvince(province);
    address.setPostalCode(postalCode);
}
```

---

```
In my Address class I have a constructor and setters.
```

When I'm testing,

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Employee s1 = new Employee("John Doe");
    s1.changeAddress("0141", "No5 Road", "Seattle", "WA", "65897");
```

This doesn't work, because I didn't create an address class. 
so that made me try: 
Address a1 = new Address();
but how do I link the new address and the employee class together? 
I'm not even sure if I am supposed to manually create an address class using Address a1 = new Address() in my tester; or if I am able to include this in my Employee class so I am able to call the changeAddress method without typing out the new address class every time.

The change address method is in the employee class. The address class only has a constructor and setters.

Comment: In the Employee constructors you are creating a new instance of Address. So Address object is already available by the time you call s1.changeAddress(...), hence s1.Address.province etc., should get you values. So what exactly is the problem you are facing?

Comment: What do you mean by this : "This doesn't work, because I didn't create an address class".